# In SSIS, add the EXCEL file name as a column in the results dataset

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ssis, ssis-2012

Using SSIS, uploading from an **EXCEL file** to SQL Server database table, I need to add the EXCEL file name as a column in the results dataset. I am able to create an EXCEL FILE source, get the data from the EXCEL, and load it into an OLE DB Destination but I am missing the step to add the filename to the dataset.

Comment: You need a Variable to hold the name of the spreadsheet and then inject it into the data flow via a Derived Column https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/05/ssis-what-is-name-of-file.html

Answer (score 0):

Most files like this are loaded through a foreach loop where you are looking in a folder for a file that matches a pattern...  d:\data*.xlsx for example.

In that foreach you are saving the the path to a variable.

In the data flow you can add a derived column and add that variable to your data flow and ultimately to the database.